# Creating sparse matrix from a data frame in R

Tags: r

Given a dataframe that has multiple objects mapped to the same person:

```
mike toy
mike golf
mike swim
mike call
tom eat
tom sleep
nate eat
```

how can i generate a matrix that has the counts of each of the elements and NA in the rest?:

```
     toy    golf   swim  call  eat  sleep 
mike 1      1        1     1    NA     NA
tom  NA     NA       NA    NA   1      1
nate NA     NA       NA    NA   1      NA
```

Comment: Are you solving an assignment? There seems to be no research effort or effort in attempting something. Did you search here on SO?

Comment: Have a look at [**these posts**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reshaping+a+data.frame+acast).

Comment: Yes, I did the research, but the solutions appeared to be too verbose and needed packages such as reshape. I didn't know I needed a the table function and that was really troubling since I couldn't search for that keyword. The posts you sent were not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> df
    V1    V2
1 mike   toy
2 mike  golf
3 mike  swim
4 mike  call
5  tom   eat
6  tom sleep
7 nate   eat
> table(df)
      V2
V1     call eat golf sleep swim toy
  mike    1   0    1     0    1   1
  nate    0   1    0     0    0   0
  tom     0   1    0     1    0   0
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a succinct solution!